# Python Size problem in password generator

Tags: python-3.x, password-generator

This is a password generator. Can some one tell what `size` is doing in this code? Is it important or can I remove it?

```
import string
import random

def pw_gen(size = 10, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation):
   return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(size))

print(pw_gen(int(input('How many characters in your password?'))))
```

Comment: `size` determines the length of the generated password. You cannot remove it as it is used in the `range` function.

Comment: it's a default parameter. you can use it like `pw_gen(size=int(input('How many characters in your password?')))`

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you want to have a default value for a function, you can assign it a value in the function definition. This means that if no value for size is provided, it will default to 10, but if a value is provided the code uses that. If you want to get rid of all the parameters and just use the defaults you could do:

```
import string
import random

def pw_gen():
   chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
   return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(10))

print(pw_gen())
```